# Hide apex:column with IF condition

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to hide the headerValue of Billing Account column, IF Entitas_X__c == 'Pusat'.. I tried using render inside the apex:column tag but nothing happen..

```
 <apex:column headerValue="Billing Account" > 
    <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Billing_Account__c}" rendered="{!if(var.vp2.Entitas_X__c=='Pusat',false,true)}"/>
 </apex:column>
```

Comment: You want to hide the headerValue only or the entire column? If entire column needs to be hidden, you can use rendered in `apex:column` too. Like `<apex:column headerValue="Billing Account"  rendered="{!if(var.vp2.Entitas_X__c=='Pusat',false,true)}"/ > 
    <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Billing_Account__c}" rendered="{!if(var.vp2.Entitas_X__c=='Pusat',false,true)}"/>
 </apex:column>`

Comment: Thanks @HemantJain .. Yes I want to hide the entire column, I tried using rendered in apex:column tag too but nothing happen..

Answer (score 2):

While you can fundamentally achieve conditional rendering in an `<apex:column>` header using conditional text in an [`<apex:facet>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_facet.htm#!) component, you're not going to be able to conditionally hide the column header based upon the contents of a single line item.

In order to do that, what you'd need to do is pre-compute in your Apex controller whether or not the column header should be shown based on the sum total of all of your line items and populate some controller property (say `showHeader`), and then include a facet:

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">
        {! IF(showHeader, "Header Name", "")
    </apex:facet>
    <!-- column content here -->
</apex:column>
```